# Eliminar cuadricula google maps personalizado

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, map

Llevo mucho rato intentando poner un mapa personalizado en mi página web y no hay manera de que me quede bien.

Mi mapa sale de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero es eliminar las linias blancas que forman cuadrados.

Estoy trabajando sobre una plantilla de wordpress, y lo que no entiendo es que si pongo el codigo en una plantilla como estoy haciendo aparece mal, pero si lo pongo en jsfiddle aparece bien...

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar porque me estoy volviendo loco!

Grácias

Comment: re recomiendo cambiar tu key de google , la dejastes publica en el enlace

Answer (score 0):

Es un bug(https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6594) que ocurre en el navegador Google Chrome, no es que estés haciendo algo mal, prueba en otro navegador como Firefox y las lineas horizontales y verticales no se muestran.

Comment: 2 comentarios, una fuente oficial que puedas citar donde se corrobore lo que mencionas acerca del bug, además como supiste de que el OP esta usando Google Chrome; en la pregunta no lo indica

Comment: Por que solo ocurre en Google Chrome, editado, Saludos!